# Load an image with only some character begin of the filename in react

Tags: reactjs

I have these images that begin with code number in React assets folder:

```
    10000_clear_large.png

    10000_clear_large@2x.png

    21021_fog_light_partly_cloudy_large.png
```

And in app I just get these codes individually from API.
How can I to load
`10000_clear_large.png`
only with code
`10000`?
Note: these codes are unique for each image file and I need a solution that works with many images.

Edit: an example:

Image.js

```
export default function Image({fileName, altImage}) {

  // I have only '10000',
  //and I need to load image begin with '10000' like '10000_clear_large.png'

  return <img src={require(`./assets/${fileName}`)} alt={altImage} />
}
```

ImageContainer.js

```
import {useState} from 'react';
import useFetchData from './fetch-data.js';
import Image from './Image.js';

export default function ImageContainer() {
  const [code, setCode] = useState(0); // after fetch data set to '10000'
  const data = useFetchData();

  if (data) setData(data.code); // result = '10000'

  return <Image fileName={code} altImage='icon' /> // fileName = '10000'
}
```

All images are in assets folder

Comment: Can you construct an example of how the process should be? For example: **API** *sends* code **10000**, App needs to *convert* **10000** to **10000_clear_large.png**, then *retrieve* this image from local storage.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you know the list of assets and ideally, you could change their names to resemble the API response, however, there are other ways you could solve the problem.

Let's say that you know the list of all the images and let's make an array of the names:

```
const imageArray = ["10000_clear_large.png","10000_clear_large@2x.png"," 21021_fog_light_partly_cloudy_large.png"];
```

Let's assume that the code you receive from API is:

```
let code = 10000
```

You can simply fetch the fileName that resembles this code as:

```
const fileName = imageArray.filter(image => image.split('_')[0] === String(code))[0]
```

I have assumed a lot of things here but I hope it helps!

Comment: I have an array of file names images, but I'm curious about a way to load images by their beginning character from each file. thanks buddy

Comment: This did not help? By the above way, you can get the file name based on the code from API.

Comment: Yes sure, your solution has already applied but I think it's possible to another approach